# How do you use the TTY (without X server) on one screen, and X on the other?

Tags: lightdm, screen, tty, virtual-console

While playing around with Ubuntu, I turned off the window manager. Unable to operate the terminal in xserver, I jumped over to a bash command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>), and relaunched `lightdm`.

After having no results I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> again, and my two screens (one was turned off) split between xserver and bash! I could put in any command I wanted, and it would affect the xserver as long as I typed `DISPLAY=:0` before the command. The only drawback is the keyboard only works for the bash.

It got me thinking... *Is there a way I could do the above again, but easier and more conventional? (through a command maybe?)* It's really neat, and even if it was possibly a glitch, it looked liked it was made to split like this through a setting or something.

**Edit:** Here's a solution to the question above:

Do the above steps (besides closing the window manager XD). This time, the keyboard is actually being shared between X11 and bash! Like the answer says, to turn off the keyboard for the bash, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> or<kbd>F8</kbd> to go to the display server. In order to use the bash without affecting your desktop,open a text editor so your keystrokes are ignored for the most part. If you are using nano in bash, the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> will trigger "open" in gedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably possible although I never tried.

If you have a single video board and that's an NVidia that you use with the NVidia proprietary drivers, then it won't work (and in that case what you saw was just a "lucky" side effect of some bug.) This is because they (NVidia) do not "properly" divide each video port in a distinct video port.

However, it should be possible with other configurations (2 video boards or 2 ports on a video board with a free driver from Linux) by configuring X11 as one screen per video and/or port. It's actually called a multi-seat configuration. Only that requires having at least two keyboards and two monitors (you probably do not need a second mouse in the console, although it can be nice to have such.)

By default the multi-seat will start both systems in lightdm, but you should be able to use Ctrl-Alt-F1 in one or the other. Obviously, I do not think that a standard way of doing things, so it may or may not work as expected. It may very well stop both X11 sessions to consoles... You'll have to play with the settings to see whether you can reach that specific configuration.

Once you are done with the console, you can then use Alt-F7 or Alt-F8 to come back to the X11 session.